# CSS: How to set 'default' font size for mobile devices matching the device accessibility settings?

Tags: css, media-queries, accessibility, responsive, font-size

How to set the font size in CSS for a mobile viewport that will always match a mobile device default system font size (including the custom accessibly zoom factor defined by the user in the device system settings)?

The assumption is that there is already a property defined mobile media query such as `@media (max-width: 600px)` (simplified for brevity) and a meta definition such as e.g. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`.

My expectation was that setting something like

```css
p {font-size: 100%}
```

would work but this results in mis-matched font sizes on different devices, i.e. depending on the device pixel density and screen size it will not render in the same size as the 'regular' font size including accessibility settings.

Also tried

```css
p {font-size: medium}
```

but apparently this renders a size that ignores the device's accessibility settings.

Comment: p {font-size: 1rem} , any problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a unit called `rem` and `1rem` equals the height definded in `html {}`.

```
html {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

So a user can set up his preferences for default HTML font-size, you don't override them and just use `1rem` to set default font-size to something.

```
p {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

More about rem: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: `1rem` seems to render the same size as `medium` and does not take into account the zoom factor defined in accessibility settings ; I have not set a font-size for `html` since I want to avoid an explicit value and allow the device use whatever is the system settings.